# Show that $W = \langle v_1 + \dots + v_n\rangle $ is a submodule of $V$ .

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G = S_n$. Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ with basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Then $V$ is an $FG$-module with action defined by setting $g · v_i = v_{g(i)}$ for all $g \in G$ and $1\leq i \leq n$ and extending linearly.

i) Show that $W = \langle v_1 +\dots+ v_n\rangle$ is a submodule of $V$.

I can show that for a finite basis that $W$ would be a submodule.

Let $G = S_3$ is the symmetric group on $3$ letters.
Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ with basis $B = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. 
Define an action of $G$ on $V$ by setting $g·v_i =v_{g(i)}$ for $g\in G, i=1,2,3$ and extending linearly.

So, if $g = (1, 2, 3)$ then
$$g·v_1 =v_2\\ g·v_2 =v_3\\ g·v_3 =v_1,$$ and if $$v=\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_iv_i \in V$$ then

$$g \cdot v = \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_ig \cdot v_i = \lambda_1v_2 + \lambda_2v_3 + \lambda_3v_1.$$
If $W=\langle v_1+v_2+v_3\rangle$, then $g·w=w $ for all
$g \in G$. So $$W = \langle v_1 + v_2 + v_3\rangle$$ is called a submodule of $V$.

But I am unsure how to apply this to an infinite amount.
Thanks.

Comment: And what are the lovely squares supposed to represent?

Comment: sorry I can't see any squares, perhaps my use of lamda isn't compatible?

Comment: The symbol before v1 in your title and at the end of the formula for $W$. Also, put all formulas into mathjax (dollar signs at both ends).

Comment: is that any better?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "infinite" amount. Your proof for $3$ works just as well for a general $n$.

Take any $g\in S_n$ and any sum

$$v=\lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\right) \in W$$
Now $$g\cdot v=g\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda v_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda v_{g(i)}=\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n v_{g(i)}=v.$$

Comment: oh my confusion i suppose starts from how i would rewrite 
$$g·v_1 =v_2\\ g·v_2 =v_3\\ g·v_3 =v_1,$$ 

for n amount, like how would i 'decide' which $v_i$ goes to which

Comment: You don't know which $v_i$ goes where. You do know it goes to some other $v_j$, meaning that any sum of $v_i$ will still be a sum of $v_i$ after applying any $g$.

Comment: yeah, okay i understand that, that's kinda like what i was trying to write but how do i write that in terms of sigmas etc rather than words.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, i understand now. would it be enough to say after that, that for some $w=v_1+...+v_n$ then g.w=w for all g in G so we can conclude that W=<$v_1+....v_n> as required?

Comment: why is the first term v in W not V?

Comment: Also, is it correct to say that; $$g\cdot v_i=g\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda v_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda v_{g(i)}=\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n v_{g(i)}=v_j.$$
or not? somehow showing that the $v_i$ is sent to some $v_j$ by the action?

Comment: It's correct, if a little complicated.

Comment: okay, i just wanted to make sure i was understanding what it is doing. 
so now i can introduce $w=v_1+v_2+...+v_n$ and say that g.w=w for all g in G so W=<$v_1+....v_n$>, can i state this or is there more to it that i must show?

Comment: That is, I think, the easiest and most elegant way to go.

Comment: so i dont have to show it i can just state it?

Comment: Just show $g\cdot w = w$ (not difficult). Then explain that since every element $v\in W$ is $v=\lambda w$, this means that $g\cdot v = \lambda(g\cdot w)=\lambda w = v$.

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but in this case is w a single element?

Comment: You defined $w$ in your comment as $w=v_1+\dots+v_n$

Comment: oh yes, sorry i am getting confused! also, why in ;
$$v=\lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\right) \in W$$
is v in W not V?

Comment: Because that's the elements you need to prove the property for.

Comment: oh in the example i have in my notes for $S_3$ it is $$v=\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_iv_i \in V$$

Comment: In the general case you get $$g\cdot v=\sum_{i=1}^n λ_i g\cdot v_i = \sum_{i=1}^n λ_i v_{g(i)} = \sum_{j=1}^n λ_{g^{-1}(j)} v_{j},$$ which in general will not be a multiple of the original $v$. Only a symmetric configuration of the coefficients leaves them invariant under permutation.